# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play' discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Every first time, I type "!music song" in chat, it says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'`. But if I type again the "!music song" , the bot is playing a music. How can i fix this? Thanks already.
My codes here:

````
@client.command()
  async def music(ctx,song : str):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
  
    if voice is None or not voice.is_connected():
      await channel.connect()
      
    
    song_there = os.path.isfile("Music/{}.mp3".format(song))
    if song_there == True:
      voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(('Music/{}.mp3'.format(song))))
      await ctx.send('{} playing! <:white_check_mark:853651360666877972>'.format(song))
    else:
      await ctx.send("This file does not exists")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initialising `voice` again after `await channel.connect()` in your `if` statement:

```
if voice is None or not voice.is_connected():
    await channel.connect()
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
```

Although, you should probably run `channel.connect()` before the function call, that way you can avoid retrying to initialize the `voice`.